# Looping MD5 hash for files causes memory leak

Tags: java, hash, memory-leaks, md5

In my program I need to check the MD5 hash of 1000+ files, but unfortunately it causes a huge memory leak for some reason. 
Is there a way to optimize my code?

(**I have tried [FastMD5](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php), java.nio, java.io, etc. The problem is not the actual code**)

```
        File[] directory = new File("/PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/LOTS/OF/FILES").listFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < directory.length;i++){

        System.out.println(MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(directory[i])));

        }
```

Comment: You're not closing the file input stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the FastMD5 library that your current code is using.  I tried adding this as a comment to your question, but Stack Overflow says it's too long, so I'm posting it as an answer and hoping that it will be close enough to let you figure out the issue.  I tried reproducing the error, but the sample code you gave worked fine for me.  I created a directory with 10,000 files like so:

`# mkdir bigdir`

`# $I=0 ; while test $I -lt 10000 ; do echo $I > bigdir/$I ; done`

Running your code printed 10,000 hashes as expected and the JVM exited normally.

Could you post the specific stack trace that you're getting?  I suspect that it's just coincidence that it is dying during the MD5 calculation and the memory leak might be elsewhere.  Would it also be possible for you to try your code on a different OS in case you're hitting an OS specific bug?

One thing that I noticed when first trying your code on my "~/Downloads/" folder was that it threw an IOException when it encountered an item in the directory list that was actually a directory itself.  So maybe you have something other than files in that directory that is throwing things off (e.g., and infinite loop symlink, reparse point, etc.).

Comment: Could you try running the code on a folder with  ~1000 files of 2MB-3MB? This is my exact situation and if you do that and don't have any problems then the problem is with my system.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just tried it on a directory containing 10,000 files, all randomly generated and all between 2MB and 3MB.  It worked fine - no errors.  Here's how I generated the test files:
`main (String[] arg)...
Random r = new Random();
File dir = new File(arg[0]);
int maxFile = Integer.parseInt(arg[1]);
for (int i = 1; i <= maxFile; i++) {
    File f = new File(dir, "" + i);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
    for (int i2 = r.nextInt(1024 * 1024) + 2 * 1024 * 1024; i2 >= 0; i2--) {
        out.write(r.nextInt());
    }
    out.close();
}`

Comment: Still having memory issues. Well at least I've proven that the problem is somehow with my system and not with the library. 
Thank you.
Any suggestion on what it may be?

Comment: Did you try generating a directory of nothing but random files using the code I posted?  If not, try that since the problem could be with something inside the directory you were using before.  The 2nd thing I'd try is having your code print the file name instead of the hash, so that you can see what it is checking.  This may make it more obvious if you have an infinite loop or infinite recursion either in your directory structure or in the more complex code which the sample you gave is presumably a simplification of.  Running 'sort' on the output of that may help too.

Comment: I tried to generate the files like you did. After that I ran the code on the new directory created. Same result. Any suggestions on system-spesific problems?

Comment: Could you post the actual stack trace that you're getting when it dies?

Comment: There is no exception thrown. It just uses up lots of memory and only frees some when it reaches a really low amount of RAM.
Is there any chance the program is saving the files to memory? I'm just iterating over the folder and running your library.

Comment: I called Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() and printed each element:
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1567)
model.Test.main(Test.java:46)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

Comment: I don't think that's a memory leak, given that the JVM recovers the memory when it gets low.  You could restrict the amount of memory that the JVM can use via something like the -Xmx option.  Or you could run your program in a profiler, see what it is that is being instantiated most, and alter the code to recycle that object or data structure rather than creating a new one each time.

Comment: I'll try -Xmx. 
The whole program is the code written, which only uses FastMD5, which I'm sure is memory efficient. 
Could it be a problem just with my Mac? (weird as it may be)

Comment: When I ran your code without problems it was on a Mac too (10.7.5), so there's at least nothing wrong which occurs on all Macs. Still, if you want to reduce memory usage, I'm near positive that's possible.  The method MD5.getHash(File) is just a static convenience method and it doesn't attempt to reuse any data structures between calls. I would suggest that you mimic what MD5.getHash(File) does, but reusing data structures. At the very least, you could eliminate all but one of the byte[] instantiations, which currently occur once per file given your code and which uses 64K of memory each time.

Comment: Beyond that, most importantly, run your code through a profiler to see where the memory is actually going because you can probably reuse other structures too.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment, this is how you should ensure that the file stream is closed to prevent memory leaks:

```
final File[] directory = new File("/PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/LOTS/OF/FILES").listFiles();
for(int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++)
{
    try(final FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(directory[i]))
    {
        System.out.println(DigestUtils.md5Hex(file));
    }
    catch(final IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or alternatively if you don't use Java 7:

```
final File[] directory = new File("/PATH/TO/FOLDER/WITH/LOTS/OF/FILES").listFiles();
for(int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++)
{
    FileInputStream file = null;
    try
    {
        file = new FileInputStream(directory[i]);
        System.out.println(DigestUtils.md5Hex(file));
    }
    catch(final IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                file.close();
            }
            catch(final IOException ex)
            {
                //Ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hoped that such a simple answer would solve my 2 week problem, but unfortunately the program still leaks memory. Any ideas?

Comment: @ItaiHay There's nothing else in the code you provided that could cause a memory leak.

Comment: I somehow keep getting the memory leak, even with external libraries. Could this be a system-specific problem?

Comment: So there's a memory leak in the library you're using.